# stability and asymptotic stability: unstable but asymptotically convergent solution of nonlinear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider nonlinear systems of the form $X(t)'=F(X(t))$, where $F$ is smooth (assume $C^\infty$). Is it possible to construct such a system (preferably planar system) so that $X_0$ is an unstable equilibrium, but all nearby solution curves tend to $X_0$ as $t \to \infty$? If so, how? A conceptual construction is enough. What will the phase portrait look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Definition of stability:
>
> Suppose $X^∗$ ∈ $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an equilibrium point for the differential equation
> $$X′ = F(X).$$
> Then $X^∗$ is a stable equilibrium if for every neighborhood $\mathcal{O}$ of $X^∗$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is a neighborhood $\mathcal{O}_1$ of $X^∗$ in $\mathcal{O}$ such that every solution $X(t)$ with $X(0) = X_0$ in $\mathcal{O}_1$ is defined and remains in $\mathcal{O}$ for all $t > 0$.

and

> Definition of asymptotic stability:
>
> If $\mathcal{O}_1$ can be chosen so that, in addition to the properties for stability, we have $\lim_{t \to \infty} X(t) = X^∗$, then we say that $X^∗$ is asymptotically stable.

The exact problem:

> In the definition of an asymptotically stable equilibrium point, we required that the equilibrium point also be stable. This requirement is not vacuous. Give an example of a phase portrait (a sketch is sufficient) that has an equilibrium point toward which all nearby solution curves (eventually) tend, but which is not stable.

---

The $C^1$ example I found with the aid of Mathematica (I guess $C^\infty$ is not possible):

```
StreamPlot[{x^2 + (-(x^2 + 1/16) (y - 1/2)^3) Boole[y >= 1/2], -y + (y - 1)^2 y Boole[y >= 1] - 500 (y - 2)^4 Boole[y >= 2] + (x + 1)^3 Boole[x <= -1] + (x - 1)^3 Boole[x >= 1]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

The phase portrait is [here](http://pdf2jpg.net/picture.php?pic_index=1&presentation_method=inline) (I don't have privilege to post image; you can always run Mathematica with the above code to get the phase portrait). The example is unprecedentedly ugly, but at least it works.

This is inspired by the system
$$x'=x^2,$$
$$y'=-y.$$
and in a small neighborhood of 0 (actually $[-1,1] \times [-\infty, 1/2]$), the system is exactly the above simple simple. All solutions nearby 0 goes back to 0, since nearby solutions in the left half plane naturally converge to 0, and nearby solutions in the right half plane first converge to the $x$-axis, then wind back to the left half plane.

Answer (score 1):

> **Definition** (Verhulst 1996)
>
> The equilibrium solution $X_c$ is called *asymptotically stable* if there exists a $\delta(t_0)$ such that
> \begin{equation}
> ||X_0 - X_c|| \le \delta(t_0) \implies \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} ||X(t;t_0,X_0) - X_c|| =0
> \end{equation}

So no, you're essentially asking can a system be both asymptotically stable and unstable which is a contradiction.

**EDIT**:

Glendinning's text refers to this definition as quasi-asymptotic stability to differentiate it from 'direct' asymptotic stability (solutions are both quasi-asymptotically stable and Lyupanov stable).

As an example he presents this equation:
\begin{equation}
\dot{r} = r(1-r^2) \qquad \dot{\theta} = 2\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta\right),
\end{equation}

which has an unstable critical point at $(0,0)$ a quasi-asymptotically stable critical point at $(1,0)$.

Points are attracted to the invariant circle at $r=1$. On this curve, the flow is semi-stable. If $\pi>\theta >0$ then the flow wraps around until it passes $\theta = \pi$. If $ -\pi> \theta>0$ the trajectory falls into the critical point at $(1,0)$. This is an example of a homoclinic orbit.

In the example provided, the critical point at $(1,0)$ is a saddle. Which, if all we considered was the linearised system, is unstable. Indeed it is Lyapunov unstable as there is a trajectory that leaves any $\epsilon$-ball about $(1,0)$.
However, in nonlinear systems the linearisation is often not sufficient,
especially with saddles, which are often the cause of a whole bunch of interesting behavior that aren't represented in the linearisation, like homoclinic and heteroclinic connections.

I think the confusion comes from how you/they define instability.
The texts I refer to define a critical point as *unstable* if it is not Lyapunov stable or 'Quasi-Asympotically' stable. However if all you go off is the linearisation then i'd imagine the example is what you're after.

Comment: Actually the problem is that my book (Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos, by M. Hirsch, S. Smale, and R. Devaney) says, the definition of asymptotically stable requires stability in it, and the stability is not vacuum. Then it says that you can find systems such that all nearby solutions converge to equilibrium asymptotically, while the equilibrium itself is not stable (in the sense that nearby solutions can exit some ball).

Comment: I can't find such a system. That's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but sorry, no, it has nothing to do with linearization. My bad not giving the exact definitions I use. I've managed to hammer out an example at last. I'll post it below along with the definitions.

Comment: Oh this problem is posted long ago. However, I still have one question: how can I show (1,0) is saddle? Looks like the jacobian matrix at (1,0) does not have any positive eigenvalues. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I didn't study user77430's example in detail, but a quick look at the phase portrait drawn by Mathematica seems to confirm that his example works well. This would be the first example I know of a $C^1$ field which admits an attractor (what MrSlunk called a "quasi-asymptotically stable equilibrium") which is unstable. Glendinning's example (which is in Glendinning, Stability, Instability and Chaos, pp. 30-31) is a variant of one of the first examples of an unstable attractor given in Bhatia and Szëgo, Stability Theory of Dynamical Systems, p.59).

Comment: Maybe the first known example of an unstable attractor was given by Vinograd in 1957. It is carefully studied in the wonderful book "Stability of Motion" by Wolfgang Hahn (Springer, Berlin, 1967) at pp. 191-194.