# Differential Equations: Asymptotically stable equilibrium implies stable equilibrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question as to why a asymptotically stable equilibrium implies a stable equilibrium. My question is really just why my counter example supposedly does not work:

**Def:** The isolated equilibrium $x^*$ = 0 is asymptotically stable if, and only if, there is a circle $C_e$ : x2 +y2 < e  centered at the origin such that every orbit which begins in the circle $C_e$ at any time t = $t_0$ approaches the origin as t → +∞.

**Def:** The isolated equilibrium $x^*$ = 0 is stable if, and only if, for every circle $C_e$ : x2 + y2 < e centered at the origin, there is a circle $C_δ$, δ<e inside inside $C_e$ such that every orbit which begins in the circle $C_δ$ at any time t = $t_0$ remains in the circle $C_e$ for all times t>$t_0$.

**Counter-Example:** What if we have a circumstance where at time $t_0$ we have an orbit inside the circle but then quickly escapes the circle then proceeds to head toward the origin as t goes to infinity. This described pattern would be asymptomatically stable would it not?  My inclination would be to say that we just need to take a larger initial t value, but the definition in my book (posted below) says we should be able to take ANY time t as long as the orbit is inside the circle. So it would fail the stability definition since the orbit would get within some epsilon and delta circle/ball at time $t_0$ then it would jut out and finally return to the origin as t -> infinity. Passing the asymptotically stable but failing stable.

Thanks in advance. I'm sure I'm wrong somewhere, would appreciate the help.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389136/.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, there are two circles involved in the definition of stability.  In your counterexample, the circle you specify is which one?  As I read it, it seems to me that the circle you specify is supposed to be $C_e$.  So then, in order for it to be a counterexample, you would need to show that for **every** circle $C_\delta$ contained in $C_e$, there is a trajectory that starts in $C_\delta$ and then leaves $C_e$.  The trajectory you posit then only proves that $C_\delta$ might need to be taken smaller.

Now, before going any further, the definitions that you give seem a little strange to me.  This is because traditionally an asymptotically stable point is defined as a **stable** point that has all nearby trajectories converging into it (I double-checked Perko, Hirsch and Smale, and Guckenheimer and Holmes).  I would be interested to hear what book these definitions come from.

Comment: The definitions come from David Logan's "A first course in differential equations". Give me a few minutes to think about your first question, thanks.

Comment: Ok so my described orbit would start within the delta circle at some time t, then leave and return to converge to the origin as t -> infinity.... with that said I misunderstood that we need to only find ONE delta circle that satisfies the condition the orbit will stay in the epsilon circle. So it's clear we just need to take a smaller delta value, as you stated. Thank you for the help!.....One unrelated question since you mentioned several other authors. Do you recommend a more advanced book on differential equations? This one omits many proofs and frequently references "see more advanced text

Comment: Hirsch and Smale (1974) is the one I like the most, and it has lots of proofs.  I think Strogatz's "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos" is considered the more modern standard introduction.